# corona sdk,rotating both instances of same display object class

Tags: class, rotation, lua, coronasdk, displayobject

I have created a lua file called moonclass.lua
which created a display object of a moon
i have created two instances of this class, aka two moons,
these were created in level1.lua

however when i try to rotate both moons, only the last moon that is created will rotate, regardless of which one i refer the rotation to.

moonclasss.lua below:

```
local moon = {}

local moon_mt = { __index = moon }  -- metatable
local sprite


function moon.new(name)   -- constructor

local newMoon = {
name = name or "unnamed",

}
return setmetatable( newMoon, moon_mt)
end


function moon:draw(x,y,group)

sprite = display.newImage("image/moon.png")
sprite.x = x
sprite.y = y
physics.addBody( sprite, "dynamic", { density=1, friction=0.8, bounce=0.05, radius=145 } )
group:insert (sprite)
end

function moon:talk()    print( self.name .. " is called." )end

function moon:y(y)
sprite.y = sprite.y + y
return y
end


function moon:x(x)
sprite.x = sprite.x + x
return x
end

function moon:rotate(r)
sprite.rotation = sprite.rotation + r
return sprite
end



return moon
```

and level1.lua:

```
local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
storyboard.purgeScene ("menu")
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0, 0)

function scene:createScene(event)

local group = self.view
local background = display.newGroup()
local foreground = display.newGroup()
group:insert(background)
group:insert(foreground)

--BACKGROUND
backgroundimage = display.newImage("image/galaxy background.png")
foreground:insert(backgroundimage)
backgroundimage.x = display.contentWidth/2
backgroundimage.y = display.contentWidth/-1
require "starclass"
require "controls"

local moon = require ("moonclass")
local moon1 = moon.new("moon1")
moon1:draw(0,400,foreground)


local moon2 = moon.new("moon2")
moon2:draw(300,400,foreground)

moon1:talk()
moon2:talk()


local platform = require "platformclass"
platform.draw(512,200,foreground)
local platform2 = require "platformclass"
platform2.draw(50,0,foreground)

local rocket = require "rocketclass"
rocket.draw(200,600,foreground)


function gameloop(event)

--if (rockety > -1920 and rockety < 320) then
    --foreground.y = rockety + 320
--end
moon2:rotate(1)
moon1:rotate(-2)

end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", gameloop)

end

-- ENTER SCENE -- 
function scene:enterScene (event)

--local chapter1level1 = require("scene objects").loadlevelenterscene()


end
-- EXIT SCENE --
function scene.exitScene(event)
controlthrust:removeEventListener( "touch", thrust)
controlleft:removeEventListener( "touch", rotateleft)
controlright:removeEventListener( "touch", rotateright)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", gameloop)
end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)

return scene
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local moon = require("moonclass")
local moon2 = require ("moonclass")
```

These lines return the same object.
`require` does not load a module twice.
Second `require` simply returns the value that was returned by the first `require`.
You must define a constructor function and call it to create new object.

---

**EDIT :**

```
local moon = {}

local moon_mt = { __index = moon }  -- metatable

function moon.new(name)   -- constructor
  local newMoon = {
    name = name or "unnamed"
  }
  return setmetatable( newMoon, moon_mt)
end

function moon:draw(x,y,group)
  self.sprite = display.newImage("image/moon.png")
  self.sprite.x = x
  self.sprite.y = y
  physics.addBody( self.sprite, "dynamic", { density=1, friction=0.8, bounce=0.05, radius=145 } )
  group:insert (self.sprite)
end

function moon:talk()    print( self.name .. " is called." )end

function moon:y(y)
  self.sprite.y = self.sprite.y + y
  return y
end

function moon:x(x)
  self.sprite.x = self.sprite.x + x
  return x
end

function moon:rotate(r)
  self.sprite.rotation = self.sprite.rotation + r
  return self.sprite
end

return moon
```

Comment: if you could show me an example of a constructor i would create, as im not too sure what to add into the constructor and how i would then call it

Comment: Ive updated the code above, which now shows my constructor and how its been implemented but I'm still getting the exact same issue.

Comment: @Krisdom - `sprite` also must be private to each `moon`.  As for now, you have only one instance of `sprite` for all your `moon`s.

Comment: ...im not quite sure what you mean there

Comment: @Krisdom - `sprite` must be inside `newMoon`.

Comment: `code`sprite = "image/moon.png" has been added and `code`sprite = display.newImage(self.sprite) but still getting same result, forgive me novice ways

Comment: @Krisdom - Correct version of `moonclasss.lua` was appended to my answer.

Comment: Much appreciated. Ill give that a try and get back to you.